# serverless step function state machine not created on sls deploy

Tags: node.js, yaml, serverless, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I am trying to setup a step function in my serverless application but when I deploy the application to aws the state machine is not created for the step functions. Here is my lambda file. I have no idea what I am doing wrong on this but there must be something in my setup that is causing the state machine creation to fail.

```
service: help-please

provider:
  name: aws
  versionFunctions: false
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg
    subnetIds:
      - subnet
      - subnet
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 'xray:PutTraceSegments'
        - 'xray:PutTelemetryRecords'
        - 'sns:*'
        - 'states:*'
      Resource: '*'

functions:
upsertNewCustomerRecord:
    handler: .build/handler.upsertNewCustomerRecord
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: 'Allow'
        Action:
          - logs:CreateLogGroup
          - logs:CreateLogStream
          - logs:PutLogEvents
          - logs:DescribeLogGroups
          - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
          - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
          - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
          - cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth
          - ccognito-idp:DescribeUserPool
          - cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient
          - cognito-idp:ListUserPoolClients
          - cognito-idp:ListUserPools
          - 'xray:PutTraceSegments'
          - 'xray:PutTelemetryRecords'
        Resource: '*'
  sendNewCustomerEmail:
    handler: .build/handler.sendNewCustomerEmail
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: 'Allow'
        Action:
          - logs:DescribeLogGroups
          - logs:CreateLogGroup
          - logs:CreateLogStream
          - logs:PutLogEvents
          - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
          - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
          - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
          - cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth
          - ccognito-idp:DescribeUserPool
          - cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient
          - cognito-idp:ListUserPoolClients
          - cognito-idp:ListUserPools
          - 'xray:PutTraceSegments'
          - 'xray:PutTelemetryRecords'
        Resource: '*'
  upsertCognitoUser:
    handler: .build/handler.upsertCognitoUser
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: 'Allow'
        Action:
          - logs:CreateLogGroup
          - logs:CreateLogStream
          - logs:PutLogEvents
          - logs:DescribeLogGroups
          - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
          - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
          - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
          - cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth
          - ccognito-idp:DescribeUserPool
          - cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient
          - cognito-idp:ListUserPoolClients
          - cognito-idp:ListUserPools
          - 'xray:PutTraceSegments'
          - 'xray:PutTelemetryRecords'
        Resource: '*'

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    signupstepfunc:
      definition:
        Comment: 'Sign up step function'
        StartAt: UpsertNewCustomerRecord
        States:
          UpsertNewCustomerRecord:
            Type: Task
            Resource: 'arn'
            Next: SendNewCustomerEmail
          SendNewCustomerEmail:
            Type: Task
            Resource: 'arn'
            Next: UpsertCognitoUser
          UpsertCognitoUser:
            Type: Task
            Resource: 'arn'
            End: true

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
  - serverless-plugin-tracing
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-prune-plugin
```

Comment: Hi, are you getting any errors in the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the yaml file provided, I think the issue might be the indentation on your function definition:

```
functions:
upsertNewCustomerRecord:
    handler: .build/handler.upsertNewCustomerRecord
    iamRoleStatements:
```

Must be replaced by this:

```
functions:
  upsertNewCustomerRecord:
    handler: .build/handler.upsertNewCustomerRecord
    iamRoleStatements:
```

Can you make this change and try once?

Comment: Actually that was from pasting the code here on stack overflow. All formatting is done correctly I actually ended up figuring out the issue. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately I figured out that I fat fingered a back slash in my buildspec file and that's what caused this to occur be wary of doing this because when deploying using serverless your build won't fail you'll have to dig into every file just to figure out what's going on. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: So this is a bug in serverless, not reporting an error and failing silently.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i simply forgot to put End: true at the last stage of the step functions. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Please provide a more comprehensive example for your suggestion, for instance; a more detailed code example could work better for the fellow to understand.